# connecting a PS2 keyboard to Mac

Tags: keyboard

I have a keyboard that has only a PS2 interface. I tried setting a PS2 to USB connector over it and connected to Mac. The keyboard does not work. It works fine on a Windows XP though.

Is there a way I can get this PS2 interfaced keyboard to work for Mac ? (assuming there is no information on support of Mac)

Comment: Looks like there a lot of variance among the PS/2 to USB converters that actually convert the keyboard signal to USB. Varying support between operating systems, drivers, as well as varying quality (simultaneous keypresses, latency). I could really use a recommendation in this area for use with a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need something like [this](http://www.clickykeyboards.com/index.cfm/fa/items.main/parentcat/11298/subcatid/0/id/179740) (Good info on the page too). I've never used one of those so I can't vouch for the specific device or vendor.

Comment: The option looks great. I remember trying out which said its an adapter, but did not work.

Comment: I bought this and its working - http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=155_TU-PS2&cat=49