# Connecting a PC PS/2 keyboard to Mac

Tags: keyboard, usb, pc

I've just bought a PS/2 to USB cable to use PS/2 PC keyboard (Compaq SK-2860 and Packard Bell 6301N) in my Mac (OS X 10.8.4) because my Mac's wireless keyboard doesn't work:

[image]

…but my Mac does not identify the keyboard. I've got this window:

[image]

…but when I press the key to the right of  <kbd>shift</kbd> nothing happens.

The cable works in Windows XP, and Linux Ubuntu well. I've seen this similar [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21716/connecting-a-ps2-keyboard-to-mac) but please note my issue is related to a specific **PC** keyboard. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are the steps I've follow to use my keyboard, I've tried so many things that I don't know which step is mandatory:

- Shut down Mac and wireless keyboard
- Plug in the keyboard with the PS/2 USB adapter
- Switch on Mac

If Mac is stuck to the first gray window try to use a different USB in my case if I use the first USB the keyboard doesn't work but if I use the fourth it  works.

If the keyboard still doesn't work I've try to install PS/2 driver with the Kext Utility.

Maybe first you should remove:

`/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist`

At the login the keyboard should be operative so you can write the password with your PS/2 keyboard. I simply ignore the Identify keyboard window that appear after login.

Answer (score 0):

I found out if you plug everything in, the PS/2 keyboard won't work right away. If you then hit the Caps Lock key on your Mac for a few times until the Caps Lock light on the PS/2 keyboard turns on and off, then it will start working. Strange.